# Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on string in

Tags: php, mysql, date

Quiero ver la diferencia de días entre la fecha actual y el dato del input, pero me sale este error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on string in

Este es el código:

```
<input type="date" class="datapicker" required="" name="VEHICLE_DATE_EXPIRATION_SURELY" value="<?php $fechabd1= $fila["VEHICLE_DATE_EXPIRATION_SURELY"];

if($fechabd1==""){

    }
else{
        echo $fechabd1->format('Y-m-d');
    }
 ?>" min="<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota'); $fechaactual1 = date("Y-m-d");ECHO $fechaactual1; ?>">
 <?php 
    $fechahoy=date("Y/m/d");
    $interval = $fechahoy->diff($fechabd1);
    echo $interval->format('%R%a días');
  ?>
```

Comment: [`diff()`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php) funciona con objetos `DateTime` no con cadenas. Por lo tanto, a partir de tus cadenas debes crear dos objetos `DateTime` para compararlos. Por ejemplo: **`$dateDB=new DateTime($fechabd1); $dateHoy=new DateTime('now'); $interval = $dateHoy->diff($dateDB);`**. Ignora la creación de `$dateDB` si ya tienes una fecha válida creada de ese valor... no me queda claro por los manejos extraños que haces de `$fechabd1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenemos que el método [`date`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

> Devuelve una cadena de fecha formateada. Si se usa un valor no numérico para **timestamp**, se devuelve **FALSE** y se emite un error de nivel **E_WARNING**.

Es precisamente por esta razón que al hacer:

```
$fechahoy=date("Y/m/d");
$interval = $fechahoy->diff($fechabd1);
```

Obtienes el error.

### Solución:

Deberías usar [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) para crear la variable `$fechahoy` y poder usar `diff`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$fechahoy = new DateTime();
$interval = $fechahoy->diff($fechabd1);
echo $interval->format('%R%a días');
```